# React hooks useEffect mesmo com dependência vazia executa mais de uma vez

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Estou usando o react hook useEffect para buscar os dados em uma API, quando a página carrega, useEffect executa 2 vezes, mas deveria executar apenas uma vez, já que declarei o segundo parâmetro (dependency array) como array vazio, em inspecionar elemento > network > XHR, dá pra ver que foram feitas 2 requisições.

```
const fetchWelcomeContent = async () => await api.get('welcome/getWelcomeContent').then(response => {
    setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(response.data.data))))
    setIsLoading(false)
    toastToggle('fas fa-times', 'Carregado')
}).catch(error => {
    toastToggle('fas fa-times', error.message)
})

useEffect(() => {
    fetchWelcomeContent()
}, [])
```

E ainda no console é exibida a seguinte mensagem:

```
 Line 57:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchWelcomeContent'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Se eu removo o dependency array ou coloco'fetchWelcomeContent' como dependência, resulta em um loop infinito, se eu coloco a função dentro de use effect dá outro erro.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import api from '../../services/api'
import {getToken} from '../../services/auth'
import { EditorState, convertToRaw, convertFromRaw } from 'draft-js'

import ReactPlaceholder from 'react-placeholder'
import 'react-placeholder/lib/reactPlaceholder.css'

import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg'
import 'react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css'

import XDKHead from '../../components/XDKHead'
import XDKToast from '../../components/XDKToast'
import XDKButton from '../../components/XDKButton'
import './index.css'


const Welcome = () => {

    const [ editorState, setEditorState ] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty())
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(true)
    const [ toast, setToast ] = useState({ isShowing: false, type: '', message: '' })

    const toastToggle = (
        toggleType = toast.type,
        toggleMessage = toast.message
    ) => setToast({
        isShowing:!toast.isShowing,
        type: toggleType,
        message: toggleMessage
    })

    const saveWelcome = async () => {
        await api.post('welcome/setWelcomeContent', `{
            "user":"${jwt_decode(getToken()).sub}",
            "editorContent":${JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()))}
        }`).then(response => {
            //console.log(response)
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error: ', error)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const setWelcomeContent = async () => {
            await api.get('welcome/getWelcomeContent').then(response => {
                setEditorState(EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(response.data.data))))
                setIsLoading(false)
                toastToggle('fas fa-times', 'Carregado')
            }).catch(error => {
                toastToggle('fas fa-times', error.message)
            })
        }

    }, [])

    return (
        <>private code here...</>
    ) // return
} // Welcome

export default Welcome
```

Comment: Edite a sua pergunta colocando o código completo do seu componente. ([edit])

Comment: O código em javascript está escrito errado na parte do `async` e `await` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando `async` e `await` para resolver a `promisse` e depois utilizando o `then` e com isso gerando ***duplicidade*** na requisição, mas, resolva assim:

```
function fetchWelcomeContent() {
    api.get('welcome/getWelcomeContent')
        .then(response => {
            setEditorState(EditorState
                .createWithContent(
                    convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(response.data.data))
                )
            )
            setIsLoading(false)
            toastToggle('fas fa-times', 'Carregado')
        });
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchWelcomeContent()
},[])
```

ou se ainda quiser utilizar `async` e `await`:

```
async function fetchWelcomeContent() {
    var response = await api.get('welcome/getWelcomeContent');
    setEditorState(
        EditorState
            .createWithContent(
                convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(response.data)
            )
        )
    )
    setIsLoading(false)
    toastToggle('fas fa-times', 'Carregado')
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchWelcomeContent()
},[])
```

Eu prefiro colocar a forma tradicional é mais fácil entender, fica claro ...

Comment: novic, não seria interessante declarar a função `fetchWelcomeContent()` dentro do corpo do `useEffect`? De outra forma, acredito que a mensagem de erro indicada na pergunta persiste

Comment: @yoyo pode ser declarado dentro ou fora, não muda nada em relação a execução. O problema foi como ele escreveu o código da função esse era o problema